# .bail() doesn't work with express-validator

Tags: typescript, express, validation, prisma, express-validator

I am registering a user I need a `name`, `email` and a `password`.
When there is no `name` given the backend does not need to check if the email is valid.

To my knowledge this is where [the `.bail()` functionality](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/6.9.2/validation-chain-api.html#bail) comes in of the `express-validator`. This functionality unfortunately does nothing in my case all validations run anyway.

The route: `app.post('/register', validate(createUserSchema), createUser)`;

The `validate()` function:

```
export const validate = (schemas: ValidationChain[]) => async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   await Promise.all(schemas.map(async (schema) => await schema.run(req)));

   const result = validationResult(req);
   if (result.isEmpty()) {
       return next();
   }

   const errors = result.array();
   return res.status(422).json(errors);
};
```

The `createUserSchema`:

```
export const createUserSchema = [
    body('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty().bail(),
    body('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty().bail(),
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Email is not valid').bail(),
    body('email')
        .custom((value) => {
            if (!value) return true;
            return prisma.user
                .findUnique({
                    where: {
                        email: value
                    }
                })
                .then(async (user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        return await Promise.reject(new Error('E-mail already in use'));
                    }
                    return await Promise.resolve();
                });
        }).bail(),
    body('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty().bail()
        .isLength({min: 6}).withMessage('Password must be longer than 6 characters')
        .matches(/[A-Z]/).withMessage('Password does not contain an uppercase character')
        .matches(/\W/).withMessage('Password does not contain any non-word characters')
];
```

my request payload:

```
{
    name: "", 
    email: "",
    password: ""
}
```

The response I get:

```
[
    {
        "value":"",
        "msg":"Name is required",
        "param":"name",
        "location":"body"
    },
    {
        "value":"",
        "msg":"Email is required",
        "param":"email",
        "location":"body"
    },
    {
        "value":"",
        "msg":"Email is not valid",
        "param":"email",
        "location":"body"
    },
    {
        "value":"",
        "msg":"Password is required",
        "param":"password",
        "location":"body"
    }
]
```

The response I expect (because it should bail on the first validation):

```
[
    {
        "value":"",
        "msg":"Name is required",
        "param":"name",
        "location":"body"
    }
]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here to answer my own question -_-

So I misunderstood what a `Validation Chain` is in `express-validator`.

I was under the impression that **different** validations rows formed one validation chain (so an array woud form a chain). This is not the case.
A chain is formed by the separate validation rules.

For example

```
export const createUserSchema = [
    body('name').notEmpty().withMessage('Name is required').bail(), //<--- this is a validation chain
    body('email').notEmpty().withMessage('Email is required').bail()
        .isEmail().withMessage('Email is not valid').bail()
]; // <--- The whole array does not form a chain (which is what I thought)
```

Gustavo Henke explained it [here](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/638#issuecomment-531012125).

So to achieve what I want I needed to use the `.if(condition)` validation.